# Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched error - how do I solve this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Can't find the proper solution to this problem.

I am using `[Serializable]` (MVC3 Futures) in order to have a "wizard" with separate views. Here is the code in my controller to serialize:

```
 private MyViewModel myData;
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var serialized = Request.Form["myData"];
            if (serialized != null) //Form was posted containing serialized data
            {
                myData = (MyViewModel)new MvcSerializer().Deserialize(serialized, SerializationMode.Signed);
                TryUpdateModel(myData);
            }
            else
                myData = (MyViewModel)TempData["myData"] ?? new MyViewModel();
            TempData.Keep();
        }
        protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
                TempData["myData"] = myData;
        }
```

Further along in my controller I do something like this (just a snippet - code goes through wizard with next and back button strings):

```
public ActionResult Confirm(string backButton, string nextButton)
        {
            if (backButton != null)
                return RedirectToAction("Details");

            else if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
                return RedirectToAction("Submitted");
            else
                return View(myData);
        }
```

In my `.cshtml` view, I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost())
    { 
         @Html.Hidden("myData", new MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed))
    ...
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.Step.EMail)
    ...
    }
```

Because I am using dynamics, I have to use a variable instead in the view:

```
var model = (MyViewModel) Model.myData;
```

in order to do the `@Html.TextBoxFor` above. And herein lies my probelm, because if I do `@model MyViewModel` instead, then I can't do `model.Step.EMail`. But because of dynamics, the `@Html.Hidden` won't work and I get the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   has no applicable method named 'Hidden' but appears to have an
>   extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically
>   dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the
>   extension method without the extension method syntax.

I can switch to some other way of doing this without `[Serializable]`, but then I have to convert a LOT of code. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call

```
@(InputExtensions.Hidden(Html, "myData", new MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed)))
```

instead of  `@Html.Hidden(...)`
It is calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Answer (score 8):

The extension method is not identifying the method because, the data type does not match.
Try cast as object.

```
@Html.Hidden("myData", new MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed) as Object)
```

or

```
@Html.Hidden("myData", (Object)new MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed))
```

It will works.

Comment: This solved my issue when trying to use ViewBag.Something as the value parameter. Thanks